# Using 'at' command to record video stream the next day and do it only once

Tags: linux, bash, video-streaming, at-job

I'm trying to

1. start and stream video to vlc and
2. record the same video stream to a file that starts at 05:45 am the next day

Everything works but the start time, instead of starting at 05:45 am the next day it starts immediately.  What did I miss?

```
bash -c "streamlink --stdout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOacA3RYrXk 720p | tee /tmp/water_vid/water_video-$(date +"%H:%M_%m-%d-%Y").mkv | vlc -" | at 05:45 am
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the commands, not their output

```
echo "streamlink --stdout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOacA3RYrXk 720p | tee /tmp/water_vid/water_video-$(date +'%H:%M_%m-%d-%Y').mkv | vlc -" | at 05:45 am
```